# Add Mouse Motion functionality to PyQt based Bezier Drawer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to modify my code below to take-in mouse events (click, drag, release) such that the control points can be selected and moved, resulting in change in the curve. I am not sure where to begin, any suggestions? The control points are marked as red dots, the curve is in blue.

This would basically let me modify the curve within the gui. Any reference would be appreciated as well.

```
import sys
import random
import functools

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=100)
def factorial(n):
    prod = 1
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        prod *= i
    return prod

def randPt(minv, maxv):
    return (random.randint(minv, maxv), random.randint(minv, maxv))

def B(i,n,u):
    val = factorial(n)/(factorial(i)*factorial(n-i))
    return val * (u**i) * ((1-u)**(n-i))

def C(u, pts):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    n = len(pts)-1
    for i in range(n+1):
        binu = B(i,n,u)
        x += binu * pts[i][0]
        y += binu * pts[i][1]
    return (x, y)

class BezierDrawer(QtWidgets.QWidget):
  
    def __init__(self):
        super(BezierDrawer, self).__init__()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 1500,1000)
        self.setWindowTitle('Bezier Curves')

    def paintEvent(self, e):
      
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        self.doDrawing(qp)        
        qp.end()
        
    def doDrawing(self, qp):

        blackPen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 3, QtCore.Qt.DashLine)
        redPen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 30, QtCore.Qt.DashLine)
        bluePen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.blue, 3, QtCore.Qt.DashLine)
        greenPen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.green, 3, QtCore.Qt.DashLine)
        redBrush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red)

        steps = 400
        min_t = 0.0
        max_t = 1.0

        dt = (max_t - min_t)/steps
        # controlPts = [randPt(0,1000) for i in range(6)]
        # controlPts.append(controlPts[1])
        # controlPts.append(controlPts[0])
        controlPts = [(500,500), (600,700), (600,550), (700,500),(700,500), (800,400), (1000,200), (1000,500)]
        oldPt = controlPts[0]
        pn = 1
        qp.setPen(redPen)
        qp.setBrush(redBrush)
        qp.drawEllipse(oldPt[0]-3, oldPt[1]-3, 6,6)

        #qp.drawText(oldPt[0]+5, oldPt[1]-3, '{}'.format(pn))
        for pt in controlPts[1:]:
            pn+=1
            qp.setPen(blackPen)
            
            qp.drawLine(oldPt[0],oldPt[1],pt[0],pt[1])
            
            qp.setPen(redPen)
            qp.drawEllipse(pt[0]-3, pt[1]-3, 6,6)

            #xv=qp.drawText(pt[0]+5, pt[1]-3, '{}'.format(pn))
            #xv.setTextWidth(3)
            oldPt = pt
            
        qp.setPen(bluePen)
        oldPt = controlPts[0]
        for i in range(steps+1):
            t = dt*i
            pt = C(t, controlPts)
            qp.drawLine(oldPt[0],oldPt[1], pt[0],pt[1])
            oldPt = pt

def main(args):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = BezierDrawer()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

[image]

Comment: [Qt: Graphics View Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was suggested, for more "serious" application, You should go for `GraphicsView`.
Your app was however almost done with simple drawing. It's not a big deal to to modify it to work as You want.

I made few changes to Your code. You have to make list of control points as a attribute of Your `BezierDrawer`. Then You can use events: `mousePressEvent`, `mouseMoveEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent` to interact with control points.

First we need to find out, if any point was clicked in `mousePressEvent` and then just update it's position while dragging. Every change of point position must end with `update` method, to repaint widget.

Here is modified code:

```
import functools
import random
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=100)
def factorial(n):
    prod = 1
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        prod *= i
    return prod


def randPt(minv, maxv):
    return (random.randint(minv, maxv), random.randint(minv, maxv))


def B(i, n, u):
    val = factorial(n) / (factorial(i) * factorial(n - i))
    return val * (u ** i) * ((1 - u) ** (n - i))


def C(u, pts):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    n = len(pts) - 1
    for i in range(n + 1):
        binu = B(i, n, u)
        x += binu * pts[i][0]
        y += binu * pts[i][1]
    return (x, y)


class BezierDrawer(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(BezierDrawer, self).__init__()
        # Dragged point index
        self.dragged_point = None
        # List of control points
        self.controlPts = [(500, 500), (600, 700), (600, 550), (700, 500), (800, 400), (1000, 200),
                           (1000, 500)]
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 1500, 1000)
        self.setWindowTitle('Bezier Curves')

    def mousePressEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
        """Get through all control points and find out if mouse clicked on it"""
        for control_point, (x, y) in enumerate(self.controlPts):
            if a0.x() - 15 <= x <= a0.x() + 15 and a0.y() - 15 <= y <= a0.y() + 15:
                self.dragged_point = control_point
                return

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
        """If any point is dragged, change its position and repaint scene"""
        if self.dragged_point is not None:
            self.controlPts[self.dragged_point] = (a0.x(), a0.y())
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
        """Release dragging point and repaint scene again"""
        self.dragged_point = None
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, e):

        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        self.doDrawing(qp)
        qp.end()

    def doDrawing(self, qp):

        blackPen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 3, QtCore.Qt.DashLine)
        redPen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 30, QtCore.Qt.DashLine)
        bluePen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.blue, 3, QtCore.Qt.DashLine)
        greenPen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.green, 3, QtCore.Qt.DashLine)
        redBrush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red)

        steps = 400
        min_t = 0.0
        max_t = 1.0

        dt = (max_t - min_t) / steps
        oldPt = self.controlPts[0]
        pn = 1
        qp.setPen(redPen)
        qp.setBrush(redBrush)
        qp.drawEllipse(oldPt[0] - 3, oldPt[1] - 3, 6, 6)

        for pt in self.controlPts[1:]:
            pn += 1
            qp.setPen(blackPen)

            qp.drawLine(oldPt[0], oldPt[1], pt[0], pt[1])

            qp.setPen(redPen)
            qp.drawEllipse(pt[0] - 3, pt[1] - 3, 6, 6)
            oldPt = pt

        qp.setPen(bluePen)
        oldPt = self.controlPts[0]
        for i in range(steps + 1):
            t = dt * i
            pt = C(t, self.controlPts)
            qp.drawLine(oldPt[0], oldPt[1], pt[0], pt[1])
            oldPt = pt


def main(args):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = BezierDrawer()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Premise note: while I normally don't answer such questions with a complete new implementation, the subject of higher-order Bézier curves is quite interesting and not directly available in Qt (and in any general toolkit), so I'm *breaking my general rule* to provide an expanded answer, as I believe it could be useful to others.</sup>

While the accepted answer properly addresses the issue, as stated, using the [Graphics View Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html) is almost always a better choice, as it provides more modularity, advanced interaction, optimization and features that would be difficult to implement in a standard widget (notably, transformations like scaling and rotation).

Before explaining the implementation, some important notes about the original code:

- the `factorial()` function is *slow*, and its caching is almost useless, since it will probably never be able to use any cached data due to the amount and diversity of results (there are 400 hardcoded steps, but the cache limit is set to 100); the `math` module already provides [`factorial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.factorial), which is much faster since it's purely implemented on the C side;
- the `B()` function only executes a computation, so it is almost useless; the same goes for `C()`: while creating functions may be important for readability and code separation, in this case their usability and usage makes them pointless;
- if you want a continuous dashed line for the curve, you cannot use `drawLine()`, as it will draw distinct segments: since those segments will almost always be very short, no dashed line will be ever shown; use [QPainterPath](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html) instead;
- such extensive and *repetitive* computation should never be executed in the `paintEvent()` (which can be called very frequently) and some level of caching should be preferably used; for instance, you can create an empty instance attribute (eg. `self.cachePath = None`), check if the attribute is empty in the `paintEvent()` and eventually call a function that creates the path in that case; also consider [QPicture](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpicture.html);
- (unrelated, but still important) calling `main` with `sys.argv[1:]` is a bit pointless if you still create the QApplication with the full `sys.argv`;

In the following implementation I created a main `BezierItem` as subclass of [QGraphicsPathItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicspathitem.html) which will contain the complete curve *and* embeds a child QGraphicsPathItem for the line segments and a variable number of `ControlPoint` objects, which are [QGraphicsObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsobject.html) subclasses. The QObject inheritance is to add signal support, which is required to notify about item position changes (it could be technically avoided by using a basic QGraphicsItem and calling the function of the parent, but that wouldn't be very elegant).

Note that, since the curve can potentially call the point computation thousands of times, optimization is of utmost importance: consider that for a "simple" 8th-order curve with a mere 20-step-per-point precision, the result is that the inner computation will be executed about 1200 times. With 20 points and a 40-step precision, the result is more than 16000 cycles.

The `BezierItem` also contains a list of control points as `QPointF`s for optimization reasons, and it uses two important functions: `updatePath()`, which updates the segments that connect each control point, and then calls `_rebuildPath()` which actually creates the final curve as a QPainterPath. The distinction is important as you may need to rebuild the path when the resolution changes, but the points are still the same.

Note that you used a peculiar way to show control points (a small ellipse with a very thick pen width, which results in a fancy rounded octagon due to the way Qt draw shapes). This can cause some issues in mouse detection, as shaped QGraphicsItems use their internal path and pen to build the shape for collision detection (including mouse events). To avoid these issues, I created a [`simplified()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#simplified) path based on that shape that will improve performance and ensure proper behavior.

```py
import random
from math import factorial
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class ControlPoint(QtWidgets.QGraphicsObject):
    moved = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, QtCore.QPointF)
    removeRequest = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red)

    # create a basic, simplified shape for the class
    _base = QtGui.QPainterPath()
    _base.addEllipse(-3, -3, 6, 6)
    _stroker = QtGui.QPainterPathStroker()
    _stroker.setWidth(30)
    _stroker.setDashPattern(QtCore.Qt.DashLine)
    _shape = _stroker.createStroke(_base).simplified()
    # "cache" the boundingRect for optimization
    _boundingRect = _shape.boundingRect()

    def __init__(self, index, pos, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.index = index
        self.setPos(pos)
        self.setFlags(
            self.ItemIsSelectable 
            | self.ItemIsMovable
            | self.ItemSendsGeometryChanges
            | self.ItemStacksBehindParent
        )
        self.setZValue(-1)
        self.setToolTip(str(index + 1))
        self.font = QtGui.QFont()
        self.font.setBold(True)

    def setIndex(self, index):
        self.index = index
        self.setToolTip(str(index + 1))
        self.update()

    def shape(self):
        return self._shape

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self._boundingRect

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == self.ItemPositionHasChanged:
            self.moved.emit(self.index, value)
        elif change == self.ItemSelectedHasChanged and value:
            # stack this item above other siblings when selected
            for other in self.parentItem().childItems():
                if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
                    other.stackBefore(self)
        return super().itemChange(change, value)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        removeAction = menu.addAction(QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme('edit-delete'), 'Delete point')
        if menu.exec(QtGui.QCursor.pos()) == removeAction:
            self.removeRequest.emit(self)

    def paint(self, qp, option, widget=None):
        qp.setBrush(self.brush)
        if not self.isSelected():
            qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        qp.drawPath(self._shape)

        qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.white)
        qp.setFont(self.font)
        r = QtCore.QRectF(self.boundingRect())
        r.setSize(r.size() * 2 / 3)
        qp.drawText(r, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, str(self.index + 1))


class BezierItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsPathItem):
    _precision = .05
    _delayUpdatePath = False
    _ctrlPrototype = ControlPoint
    def __init__(self, points=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.blue, 3, QtCore.Qt.DashLine))
        self.outlineItem = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPathItem(self)
        self.outlineItem.setFlag(self.ItemStacksBehindParent)
        self.outlineItem.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 3, QtCore.Qt.DashLine))

        self.controlItems = []
        self._points = []

        if points is not None:
            self.setPoints(points)

    def setPoints(self, pointList):
        points = []
        for p in pointList:
            if isinstance(p, (QtCore.QPointF, QtCore.QPoint)):
                # always create a copy of each point!
                points.append(QtCore.QPointF(p))
            else:
                points.append(QtCore.QPointF(*p))
        if points == self._points:
            return

        self._points = []
        self.prepareGeometryChange()

        while self.controlItems:
            item = self.controlItems.pop()
            item.setParentItem(None)
            if self.scene():
                self.scene().removeItem(item)
            del item

        self._delayUpdatePath = True
        for i, p in enumerate(points):
            self.insertControlPoint(i, p)
        self._delayUpdatePath = False

        self.updatePath()

    def _createControlPoint(self, index, pos):
        ctrlItem = self._ctrlPrototype(index, pos, self)
        self.controlItems.insert(index, ctrlItem)
        ctrlItem.moved.connect(self._controlPointMoved)
        ctrlItem.removeRequest.connect(self.removeControlPoint)

    def addControlPoint(self, pos):
        self.insertControlPoint(-1, pos)

    def insertControlPoint(self, index, pos):
        if index < 0:
            index = len(self._points)
        for other in self.controlItems[index:]:
            other.index += 1
            other.update()
        self._points.insert(index, pos)
        self._createControlPoint(index, pos)
        if not self._delayUpdatePath:
            self.updatePath()

    def removeControlPoint(self, cp):
        if isinstance(cp, int):
            index = cp
        else:
            index = self.controlItems.index(cp)

        item = self.controlItems.pop(index)
        self.scene().removeItem(item)
        item.setParentItem(None)
        for other in self.controlItems[index:]:
            other.index -= 1
            other.update()

        del item, self._points[index]

        self.updatePath()

    def precision(self):
        return self._precision

    def setPrecision(self, precision):
        precision = max(.001, min(.5, precision))
        if self._precision != precision:
            self._precision = precision
            self._rebuildPath()

    def stepRatio(self):
        return int(1 / self._precision)

    def setStepRatio(self, ratio):
        '''
        Set the *approximate* number of steps per control point. Note that 
        the step count is adjusted to an integer ratio based on the number 
        of control points.
        '''
        self.setPrecision(1 / ratio)
        self.update()

    def updatePath(self):
        outlinePath = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        if self.controlItems:
            outlinePath.moveTo(self._points[0])
            for point in self._points[1:]:
                outlinePath.lineTo(point)
        self.outlineItem.setPath(outlinePath)
        self._rebuildPath()

    def _controlPointMoved(self, index, pos):
        self._points[index] = pos
        self.updatePath()

    def _rebuildPath(self):
        '''
        Actually rebuild the path based on the control points and the selected
        curve precision. The default (0.05, ~20 steps per control point) is
        usually enough, lower values result in higher resolution but slower
        performance, and viceversa.
        '''
        self.curvePath = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        if self._points:
            self.curvePath.moveTo(self._points[0])
            count = len(self._points)
            steps = round(count / self._precision)
            precision = 1 / steps
            n = count - 1
            # we're going to iterate through points *a lot* of times; with the
            # small cost of a tuple, we can cache the inner iterator to speed
            # things up a bit, instead of creating it in each for loop cycle
            pointIterator = tuple(enumerate(self._points))
            for s in range(steps + 1):
                u = precision * s
                x = y = 0
                for i, point in pointIterator:
                    binu = (factorial(n) / (factorial(i) * factorial(n - i)) 
                        * (u ** i) * ((1 - u) ** (n - i)))
                    x += binu * point.x()
                    y += binu * point.y()
                self.curvePath.lineTo(x, y)
        self.setPath(self.curvePath)


class BezierExample(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.bezierScene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.bezierView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.bezierScene)
        self.bezierView.setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.bezierItem = BezierItem([
            (500, 500), (600, 700), (600, 550), (700, 500), 
            (700, 500), (800, 400), (1000, 200), (1000, 500)
        ])
        self.bezierScene.addItem(self.bezierItem)

        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        topLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(topLayout)
        topLayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Resolution:'))

        resSpin = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(minimum=1, maximum=100)
        resSpin.setValue(self.bezierItem.stepRatio())
        topLayout.addWidget(resSpin)

        topLayout.addStretch()
        addButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add point')
        topLayout.addWidget(addButton)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.bezierView)

        self.bezierView.installEventFilter(self)
        resSpin.valueChanged.connect(self.bezierItem.setStepRatio)
        addButton.clicked.connect(self.addPoint)

    def addPoint(self, point=None):
        if not isinstance(point, (QtCore.QPoint, QtCore.QPointF)):
            point = QtCore.QPointF(
                random.randrange(int(self.bezierScene.sceneRect().width())), 
                random.randrange(int(self.bezierScene.sceneRect().height())))
        self.bezierItem.addControlPoint(point)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == event.MouseButtonDblClick:
            pos = self.bezierView.mapToScene(event.pos())
            self.addPoint(pos)
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtWidgets.QApplication.primaryScreen().size() * 2 / 3


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = BezierExample()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: screenshot of the above code]

I will probably change the above code in the future, mostly to provide a valid backend for Nth-order curves without control point interaction and eventually a further subclass to add that support.
But, right now, the requested support is complete, and I *strongly* urge you to carefully take your time in studying every part of that code. The Graphics View framework is as powerful as it's complex to understand, and it may take weeks (at least!) to really get it.

As always, the basic rule remains: study the documentation. And, possibly, the source code.